# Hadoop mapreduce programming

Tags: hadoop

How do I get the sorted o/p using Hadoop mapreduce programming.

Is there any way to get final key-value pair in sorted order. ( either by key or value).

Any pointers on this greatly appreciated.

Thank You
R

Answer (score 6):

By default, MapReduce will sort input records by their keys.

However, it might help you more to download latest Hadoop release and check out examples they have. There are different sort examples as well.

If you need more information on sort order, this is how it can be changed.

The sort order for keys is controlled by a RawComparator, which is found as follows:

1. If the property mapred.output.key.comparator.class is set, an instance of that class
   is used. (The setOutputKeyComparatorClass() method on JobConf is a convenient
   way to set this property.)
2. Otherwise, keys must be a subclass of WritableComparable, and the registered
   comparator for the key class is used.
3. If there is no registered comparator, then a RawComparator is used that deserializes
   the byte streams being compared into objects and delegates to the WritableCompar
   able’s compareTo() method.
   These rules reinforce why it’s important to register optimized versions of RawCompara
   tors for your own custom Writable classes, and also that it’s straightforward to override the
   sort order by setting your own comparator.

Comment: The built-in WritableComparable classes will compare correctly, so if it's an LongWritable, it will sort in descending order. If you want your own sort order, for example sorted by a text string, and then within that order your values by a timestamp, you'll need a custom key, and a custom Sort Comparator and custom Grouping Comparator.

Answer (score 3):

"Hadoop: The Definitive Guide" 2nd edition describes global sort in chapter 8 with code samples.