# Calculating ranking in Map/Reduce

Tags: hadoop, couchdb

I have a simple problem which is hard to solve in SQL and I'm wondering if it can be done in a map-reduce system.

I want to produce rankings.  Imagine Amazon purchase database (much simplified)

```
ORDERS
ISBN  copies_purchased
AAAA   5
AAAA   1
BBBBB  3
BBBBB  4
CCCC   3
```

I want to produce the ranking table

```
rank ISBN     copies_purchased
1    BBBB     7
2    AAAA     6
3    CCCC     3
```

The map-reduce to calculated copies_purchased is obvious; calculating the rankings is less so, at least to me.

(This is not a homework problem.  I need this for my actual job.  Is that better?)

**EDIT**
I thought this would have been obvious from the title, and the tags, and the text of the question, but this is **not** a SQL question.  I want to know how to do it in map/reduce.  And yes, I have millions of rows.  Well, probably billions.

Comment: Can you explain the reason why this is "hard to solve in SQL". Your preamble leads the reader to believe that is an important piece of information. The best answers aren't the one that answer explicitly the question asked, but also look for different approaches to solve the specified question.

Comment: Have you looked at all of the word counting examples?

Comment: @Mranz -- I don't know if I can give a "reason", it just *is* hard.  There's no pure SQL solution.  In MySQL, you have to introduce a variable and iterate it; Oracle has a pseudo-variable called rownum but for many years, it didn't work (it counted the rows before ordering, which is useless).  I think my dataset is too large for MySQL, so I'm looking at M/R solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CouchDB, map/reduce builds 1-dimensional indexes so that couch can quickly find any information by key.

First, map/reduce builds the `copies_purchased` view pretty easily, as you say. But the key space is ISBN ID, it is the *values* that you care about, but they are in no particular order.

For small applications, people simply fetch the entire data set and sort in-memory. That is a great shortcut if you know your requirements; but it does not scale.

A scalable solution is to place *these* rows into their own database. A *second* map/reduce can emit keys from `copies_purchased` and values back to the ISBN. (There is no need for a reduce step.)

```
Key                 Value
copies_purchased    ISBN

7                   BBBB
6                   AAAA
3                   CCCC
```

You can fetch the top N rows, or you can find, e.g., the seventh-ranked book by querying with `?skip=6&limit=1`

Comment: I need to do the *opposite*: instead of choosing a ranking and getting the ISBN, I have the ISBN, and want to know the ranking.  Is there any way to reverse the `skip` thing?

Comment: Do you need it for all rankings with the same accuracy? Or is it ok to return "More than 1000" for the long tail?

Comment: The answer then is to make a *third* database which switches them around again based on the results. That wouldn't be so bad but none of that is automated in CouchDB so it would be tedious and error-prone. I will ask around among some Couch people if there is a better answer. But IMO it is becoming clear we are beginning to talk about **reports** on the data rather than real-time updates.

Answer (score 0):

If the rank is determined by the number of copies sold, then you can build that table using a sql select cursor:

```
select * from ORDERS orderby copies_purchased desc
```

And then assign a rank based on the order you retrieve records

```
while (nextRecord) currRecord.rank = i++;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you would do this using couchdb. As far as I know, there is no way to directly read couchdb data into hadoop. The closest thing I'm aware of is [Brisk](http://www.datastax.com/products/brisk), which combines hadoop and cassandra. Its also free.

Alternatively, if it did not have to be up to the minute, you could dump the relevant data to text or sequence files, and use these as your input.

I think you would have to do this in a 2 step process. First, generate the copies purchased, which is basically the word count example that is so common with hadoop.

Since you can relatively easily find out the maximum number of copies purchased by looking at the output of the copies purchased job (this may be a job in itself), you could then create a custom partitioner that will divide the products according to the copies purchased. So if you have 3 reducers, and the max you sell is 600 copies, then reducer 1 takes products selling 0 - 200 copies, reducer 2 takes products selling 201 - 400, and reducer 3 takes prducts selling 401 - 600 copies. Then you can merge the sorted reducer output files, and you then have your sorted list of copies sold.

Or for source code, check out the terasort benchmarks code [here](http://search-hadoop.com/c/Map/Reduce:/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/TeraSort.java%7C%7C+%2522hadoop+jar%2522). More info about Terasort classes [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/examples/terasort/package-summary.html).

So you end up with a workflow like:

1. A job to calculate the number of copies sold per product
2. A job that finds the highest number of copies sold, based on the output of the previous job (though you might be able to skip this step depending on how you implement sort. )
3. A job that sorts the data and gives you a sorted list of product copies sold. May be outputted over multiple files, so you might need a simple script that merges them together.

For help managing a multi step workflow like this, have a look at [Oozie](http://yahoo.github.com/oozie/) or [Cascading](http://www.cascading.org/).

For more on sorting see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074842/hadoop-mapreduce-programming#7093590).

Answer (score -3):

Its easy to solve in SQL unless you have a millions of rows.

SELECT ISBN, count(*) FROM orders GROUP BY ISBN ORDER BY 2 desc;

Comment: Uh, doesn't produce a ranking number *and* this question isn't about SQL.  (Yes, there are SQL-extensions to do the numbering but still, not the question.)